# OrientDB: Read vertex and include connected vertex rids grouped by edge classes

Tags: orientdb

I would like to display all connected record ids grouped on the edge-classes they are connected with.

```
                   V1
                   ^  
                   |
               edgeClass1
                   |
V2 <--edgeClass1-- V0 --edgeClass2--> V3
                  /  \
         edgeClass3   edgeClass4
                 \    /
                  v  v
                   V4
```

From this I would like to be able to target V0 and get the whole V0 record as well as all connected vertices grouped by their edge classes as follows:

```
{
   rid: <V0rid>
   someV0Property: someV0Value,
   edgeClass1: [<V1rid>, <V2rid>],
   edgeClass2: [<V3rid>],
   edgeClass3: [<V4rid>],
   edgeClass4: [<V4rid>]
}
```

The available edgeClasses are not known in advance, so I can't target them explicitly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi Latest possible stable version. :)